# Reducing the amount of space taken in a v-dialog

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I am trying to write a Vue 3 dialog to hold a date picker and a radio button to collect the hour.  It seems to take a great deal of space in the vertical direction.

For example I like to move the label for the radio button to be in line with the radio buttons and to reduce the amount of space taken by the rulers.

[image]

I have already turned of the chosen date, but I can not workout how to reduce the space allocated between components

Calling code

```
    <template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <date-dialog dialogTitle="Select the date"
             startDate="2018/01/01"
             endDate="2018/12/31"
             year="2018"
             :propDate="'2018-12-17T12:06:00'"
             :propHourFormated="'6'"
             @clicked="onDateClicked"
        />
      </v-col>  
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
  
</template>
<script>
import DateDialog from './components/DateDialog.vue';
export default {
  methods: {
      onDateClicked(value){
          console.log("Value is " + value)
      }
  },
  components: {
    DateDialog,
  },
}
</script>
<style>
  /* remove calander frrom date picker */
  .v-date-picker-header {
     display: none
  }
</style>
```

Dialog code

```
    <template>
  <div>
  <v-container class="fill-height">
    <v-row>
      <v-col
        cols="12"
        sm="6"
        md="4" >
        <v-dialog
          ref="dialog"
          v-model="modal"
          :return-value.sync="date"
          persistent
          width="290px" >
          <template v-slot:activator="{ attrs }">
              <!-- label="Select a date" -->
            <v-text-field v-model="computedDateFormatted"
              :label="dialogTitle" prepend-icon="mdi-calendar" readonly
               @click="modal = true" v-bind="attrs" persistent-hint >
            </v-text-field>
          </template>
          <v-card width="360px">
            <v-date-picker v-model="date" color="primary"
            :year="year" :min="startDate" :max="endDate"
            scrollable :title="dialogTitle" hide-actions >
              <!-- remove the selected date--> 
              <template v-slot:header></template>
            </v-date-picker> 
            <hr>
            <v-container>
              <v-radio-group v-model="computedHourFormatted" label="Time" inline @change="this.RBchanged">
                <v-radio label="00" value="0"></v-radio>
                <v-radio label="06" value="6"></v-radio>
                <v-radio label="12" value="12"></v-radio>
                <v-radio label="18" value="18"></v-radio>
              </v-radio-group>
            </v-container>
            <hr>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn text color="primary" @click="this.dialogOK" >OK </v-btn>
              <v-btn text color="primary" @click="this.dialogCancel" >Cancel </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions> 
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
        dialogTitle:{ type:String},
        startDate:{ type:String},
        endDate:{ type:String},
        year:{ type:String},
        propHourFormated:{ type:String},
        propDateFormated:{ type:String},
        propDate:{ type:String},
    },
    methods:{
      // inserted to show that clicking of the radio buttons is working
      RBchanged(){
        console.log('changed')
        console.log("VM "+this.hourFormatted);
      },
      dialogOK(){
          this.modal=false;
          console.log("OK " );
          this.$emit('clicked',this.date);
      },
      dialogCancel(){
          console.log("Cancelled " );
          // reset to the orginal value
          this.date= new Date(this.propDate);
          this.dateFormatted= new Date(this.propDateFormatted);
          this.modal=false;
          this.$emit('clicked',this.date);
      },
      // write a date in to the textfield object, note expects to 
      // receive a date object
      formatDate (mydate) {
        if (!mydate) 
          return null
        var hours="00",mins="00";
        if(mydate.getHours() !== "" && mydate.getHours() !==0 ){
           hours=mydate.getHours();
        }
        return mydate.getDate()+"-"+
          mydate.toLocaleString('en-GB', { month: 'long' })+" "+
          mydate.getUTCFullYear() + " "+
          hours+ ":" +
          mins
          ;
      },
      // set a value of the radio button should
      // be a value of 0,6,12,18
      formatHour(myhour) { 
      
        return myhour.toString();
      },
    },
    computed: {
      computedDateFormatted () {
        this.date.setHours(this.hourFormatted)
        return this.formatDate(this.date)
      }, 
      computedHourFormatted:{ 
        get() { 
          console.log("XXXXget #" + this.date.getHours().toString()+"#");
          return this.hourFormatted;
        },
        set(value){
          console.log("SET:Formating hours " + value);
          this.hourFormatted=value;
        }
      },
    },
    watch: {
      date (val) {
        //this.hourFormatted = this.formatHour(this.date.getHours())
        this.dateFormatted = this.formatDate(this.date)
      },
    }, 
    data () {  return {
      // starting value for the date picker
      date: new Date(this.propDate),  
      // starting value for the textfield
      dateFormatted: new Date(this.propDate),  
      // starting value for the radio buttons
      hourFormatted: this.propHourFormated,
      modal: false,
    }},
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the `height & max-height` prop to `v-dialog`. You also need to add `scrollable` prop to the component. You can also check the [component API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-dialog/).

```
<v-dialog
    ref="dialog"
    v-model="modal"
    :return-value.sync="date"
    persistent
    width="290px"
    height="400px"
    max-height="400px"
    scrollable
>
```